# Mapping (join) create table not allowing foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, join

I have these two tables for this site I'm building (login and licks).  I want to allow the user to save his favorite licks so this means I need a mapping table but it's not working.  It works without the foreign key constraint but I want/need the foreign key constraint.  I've done research and everyone says to create the mapping table as I am but it's not working. 
Can anyone tell me why this wont work?  Thank you.

Table: Login

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `login_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Table: Licks

```
CREATE TABLE `licks` (
  `lick_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lick_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lick_category` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lick_html_pg` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lick_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Table login_licks (Not woking!)

```
CREATE TABLE login_lick (
  login_id INT NOT NULL,
  lick_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (login_id, lick_id),
  FOREIGN KEY login_id REFERENCES login (login_id),
  FOREIGN KEY lick_id REFERENCES licks (lick_id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses in the foreign key definition:

```
CREATE TABLE login_lick (
  login_id INT NOT NULL,
  lick_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (login_id, lick_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (login_id) REFERENCES login (login_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (lick_id) REFERENCES licks (lick_id)
);
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32c0) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Ahh I feel dumb!  That worked thank you.  When it allows me (10 min) I'll give you the answer.  Thank you!